# $\mathcal{B}$ being the collection of all open intervals $(a,b)$ in $\mathbf{R}$ with $a,b\in\mathbf{Q}$ is a basis for $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, proof-verification

**Is the following argument correct ?**

> **Proposition.** Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all open intervals $(a,b)$ in $\mathbf{R}$ with $a<b$ and $a$ and $b$ are
>   rationals. Prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the euclidean
>   topology on $\mathbf{R}$.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all open intervals $(x,y)$ where $x,y\in\mathbf{R}$, since we know beforehand that $\mathcal{A}$ is a basis for $\mathbf{R}$, consequently given an arbitrary open set $O$ in $\mathbf{R}$, we have, for some indexed subset $J$ of $\mathcal{A}$.

$$O = \bigcup_{j\in J}(a_j,b_j)$$

Now let $j\in J$. We show that $(a_j,b_j)$ can be written as a union of intervals found in $\mathcal{B}$. We begin by defining sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ as follows
$$x_0  = y_0 = \frac{a_j+b_j}{2}$$
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{a_j+x_n}{2}\ \text{ and }\ \ y_{n+1} = \frac{y_n+b_j}{2}$$

Given thh definition of the above sequences it is evident that $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by $a$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above by $b$ consequently the converge with the limits in question being

$$r_1 = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1} = \frac{a_j+\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n}{2} = \frac{a_j+r_1}{2}$$
$$r_2 = \lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n+1} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n+b_j}{2} = \frac{r_2+b_j}{2}$$
which imply that $r_1=a_j$ and $r_2 = b_j$, given this the following inferences are immediate (for the following sequences $n\ge 1$).
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n} = a_j \ \ \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n-1} = a_j\ \ \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty}y_{2n} = b_j \ \ \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty}y_{2n-1} = b_j$$
Now given the density of $\mathbf{Q}$ in $\mathbf{R}$ we have sequences of rationals $\{p_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that 
$x_{2n}<p_n<x_{2n-1}$ and $y_{2n}<q_n<y_{2n-1},\forall n\ge 1$, the squeeze theorem then yields that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n = a_j$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n = b_j$$
consequently 
$$(a_j,b_j) = (p_1,q_1)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(p_n,x_0)\cup(y_0,q_n)$$
the claim in question is then evident.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: At first glance, it looks like the basic idea is right.  There's a simpler argument, though: given $x_0 \in U$, choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \subseteq U$, then choose $a \in (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $b \in (x_0, x_0 + \epsilon) \cap \mathbb{Q}$; then $(a,b)\in \mathcal{B}$ and $x_0 \in (a,b) \subseteq U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct, since you have no reason to suppose that $x_0,y_0\in\mathbf Q$. So, your last expression is not necessarily an union of elements of $\mathcal B$.

Given an interval $(a,b)$ of real numbers, you could simply take a decreasing sequnce $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $\left(a,\frac{a+b}2\right)\cap\mathbf Q$ and an increasing sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $\left(\frac{a+b}2,b\right)\cap\mathbf Q$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=a$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=b$. Then$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(x_n,y_n)$$and each $(x_n,y_n)$ belongs to $\mathcal B$.

Comment: Your point is legitimate, silly me for fogetting that $x_0=y_0$ coult be irrational, but can i save the above argument by considering that $(a_j,b_j) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(p_n,q_n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Comment: Thank for your counsel, your critique is always invaluable.